# Questionable Review Audit

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, review-suspension

I came across this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26680972/unsupportedmethodexception-android-studio-0-8-9/26722791#26722791) in a review audit, and I failed the audit as the system claims this is a quality post.

In my opinion, I don't think this should even be considered as an answer as it merely re-state another [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26680972/unsupportedmethodexception-android-studio-0-8-9#comment42031754_26692486) in the same page without adding any new idea to it.

I suspect the system claims this is a quality post simply because it has many upvotes, and I would like to appeal for the audit failed decision as well as hearing some thoughts from the stackoverflow community so that I can avoid this kind of audit failure in the future.

Thanks and any feedback is be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I suspect the system claims this is a quality post simply because it has many upvotes

I would guess that too (Although perhaps the algorithms are a bit more complex - not sure).

I presume you failed the audit for downvoting, or clicking "flag", and the system deemed such actions are not necessary on a quality post?

In which case, I'd tend to agree with the system, as there is nothing wrong with that answer.

> I don't think this should even be considered as an answer as it merely re-state another comment in the same page without adding any new idea to it.

It might be a short answer, but what else should they have said?
"I have this problem" - "Upgrading to Android Studio 0.9.0 fixes this issue". 
That's it - clear, concise, and answers the question. No further info needed.

We shouldn't be leaving decent answers in comments, so the user making the comment into an answer was fine - it gave the question a solid and reliable answer, and they gave credit to the original commenter.
People with the same issue might not click it from a search with "0 Answers", now they might and so helps them too.

Although, the 24 upvotes is a little OTT, but that's another debate...

Answer (score 3):

As stated by [remyabel](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278159/questionable-review-audit#comment123293_278159), upgrading a comment to an answer is fine and preferable, since comment is considered as 2nd class citizen and might be removed in any time.