# Implement vote audits

Tags: discussion, feature-request, voting

We already have review audits, which are designed to help new reviewers hone their moderation skills, while nudging more experienced users that don't seem to be paying close attention to what they're reviewing.

And I think they are a great in what they are doing. So why shouldn't we do the same for voting (up-/downvoting)?

Which brings me to the point: I want to propose that we also implement vote audits to show (new) users what they should/n't up-/downvote. Same as for review audits, vote audits would be fake posts designed as a test if you understand what should be up-/downvoted. The fake posts should be so obvious how you should vote on them and also shouldn't bother the "normal" users.

Also here a few examples how these vote audits could look like:

> #### Answer
>
> [image]
>
> #### Answer
>
> [image]
>
> #### Answer
>
> [image]
>
> #### Question
>
> [image]
>
> #### Question
>
> [image]

So I think these audits are pretty straight forward, but there are still users which vote in the wrong direction. There shouldn't be many vote audits displayed to you, just from time to time one audit.

And just as for review audits, if you fail them you will get a message like:

> **STOP! Look and Listen**
>
> This was an audit, designed to see if you were paying attention. **You didn't pass**. This post was of very poor quality - upvoting such posts hurts the ability  of others to find and answer good questions. Please try to fix such posts by downvoting or flagging as "very low quality".
>
> Don't worry, we've already handled this post appropriately - but please take a minute to look it over closely, keeping in mind the guidance above.

So vote audits should be designed to show users what posts to up-/downvote.

(Everything written above can still be changed, tweaked and is not written in stone. It should just be the general idea of what I want implemented as feature-request.)

Comment: So you propose showing these fake answers on existing questions to new users? Wouldn't that then give the wrong impression of SO?

Comment: Lol, there isn't a consensus on what exactly is worth upvoting and what isn't even among the most experienced veterans on Stack Overflow. Voting is anonymous and should stay that way. Overall I think it's still working pretty well. Someone (Shog9?) posted some stats about spurious upvotes once, proving that they aren't the big deal we tend to think they are... perhaps someone remembers the Meta Q&A.

Comment: This isn't even a consensus on what should be closed and what should  be open, or what makes a good edit.  To top it off, voting has long been considered a sacred right (of >10 rep users) to do with as they may as long as they aren't using sockpuppets or targeting specific users.  Telling people how to vote is really pushing it.

Comment: ***Highly related on Meta SE:*** http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269082/spam-voting-should-we-stop-it

Answer (score 13):

We already have a [great](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278159/questionable-review-audit?s=1%7C2.0223) [amount](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290258/poor-review-audit?s=6%7C1.9737) [of](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280398/faulty-review-audit?s=7%7C1.9729) [unhappiness](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255831/reporting-bad-review-audit?s=9%7C1.9110) over borderline *review* audits - and those are in a place where people are expecting audits. The review queues are a place where it's fairly clear what you're supposed to do in most cases - and there are policies for it.

As I understand it, you want to show these audits to users in the context of a normal Q&A thread. A couple problems that would make this worse than the audit system:

1. Users aren't expecting it (and thus would be even more unhappy when they 'fail' one), and
2. **People can vote however they like**, so long as they're voting for content and not a person. If someone thinks that a link-only answer deserves to be upvoted... we can't stop them. We can delete the answer, of course - but **voting is an intensely personal thing.**

   There are guidelines about what should and shouldn't be upvoted/downvoted, but not strict rules. I think we should keep it that way.

Comment: You're two points are excellent, but I think I would add a third: It removes the feeling of vote anonymity. With such audits, we get the feeling that people are watching us now, and would be more scared to vote. If such audit is passed or failed, and it's taken to meta, imagine the backlash for commit a [non] anonymous action.

Answer (score 7):

The reason this wouldn't work is that you can't tell someone how to vote.

Think of it like this: we know that there is bad content, and we generally know that we are supposed to push bad content off of the site.  However, there are people who will vote arbitrarily, and they make up a *small minority* of active users.

Further to that, voting on content has always been and always be subjective and time-sensitive.  I've never personally upvoted a question or answer because it had a lot of upvotes, but people do that.  Also, who's to say that content that I'd downvote *now* would be downvote-worthy (by some measure) *later*?

Lastly, I'd personally prefer it if people *didn't* vote on content that they didn't understand.  I'm not going to all of a sudden upvote a question or answer in VB because I thought it was "awesome" unless I truly understood what was being asked.  Those questions are vanishingly rare, and I'd doubt that bringing them up via audit would expose them.

I see no reason to have this feature.