# Is there a penalty for upvoting?

Tags: support

Recently I unlocked the option to upvote posts. I find that a lot of even silly questions/answers are useful for me which I want to upvote.
Is there some rule I should follow to which posts I should upvote? Is it ok to upvote a lot of posts?

Comment: 1) Hover over the upvote button and the answer will [*magically*](http://imgur.com/MXr9uBq) appear 2) *Is it ok to upvote a lot of posts?* As long as you are not target upvoting some users, there is no problem.

Comment: Does the blackening of your soul for knowing that you're making the world a worse place by actively encouraging harmful behavior count as a penalty.

Comment: @Rizier123 If you're not serially voting the user instead of the content then it's not *fraud*, and the votes won't be reversed.  But if you're knowingly upvoting bad posts, there is most certainly a problem, even though you aren't being punished for it (actually, in large part *because* you aren't being punished for it).

Comment: Lol, I know how to upvote and I know my question is silly, I just wanted to make sure I won't banned or something. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Reputation cost of actions or events is explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) in detail.

Comment: @AlexWeitz If only we could ban people for upvoting bad content...

Comment: @Servy I mean for example if you find a reference Q&A where there are 5-6 community wiki answers from one user and you read the entire thing and find it useful and upvote it all, that will most probably be reversed, even though you didn't voted on the user. That is what you have to look out for a bit. Second, I'm sorry if it sounded like this, but I'm highly against voting on bad questions or answers. They should be downvoted.

Comment: @Servy _"If only we could ban people for upvoting bad content ..."_ We should have voting decision honeypot audit questions strayed into the main page queues (newest, etc.)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ If only...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ You mean something like a [vote-audit](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/310804/3933332) to test that you don't upvote clearly bad stuff?!

Comment: @Rizier123 Yup. I start to think of such a feature request :-) ...

Comment: @Rizier123 Oops I see I've downvoted your request that time. Well I'd say we leave it like _@Hans Passant_ keeps saying: You know it when you see it.

Comment: You down voted? I hope you left the mandatory comment for your down vote @πάνταῥεῖ ...

Comment: well, there is one negative once you reach 125 rep... each upvote you cast removes one from the number of possible downvotes you can cast that day.

Comment: ' each upvote you cast removes'... not really an issue, these days:(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I find that a lot of even silly questions/answers are useful for me which I want to upvote.

It's totally on your own if you think that the question was helpful and want to upvote or downvote it:

- Voting on questions doesn't cost you any rep.
- Upvoting doesn't cost you any rep.
- Downvoting answers costs you -1 rep.

> Is there some rule I should follow to which posts I should upvote?

Yes, the reasonings appear right when you hover your mouse pointer over the up-/downvote buttons.

> Is it ok to upvote a lot of posts?

Yes it's OK, as long you are not targeting a specific users questions. You are limited to a specific number of votes per day anyway.